# proof that if $(X,d)$ is a metric and $\mathbb{R}$ has the standard topology, with $C\subset X$ that the following map is continuous.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

proof that if $(X,d)$ is a metric and $\mathbb{R}$ has the standard topology, with $C\subset X$ that the following map is continuous.

$X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $x\rightarrow d(x,C)$

where $d(x,C) = \inf\{d(x,y)|y \in C\}$.

It is vague for me because i don't really know how an open set in $d(x,C)$ looks like. Any hints for this problem?

Kees

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly show that $d(x,C)$ is even Lipschitz-continuous. First note that $d(x,C)\leq d(x,y)$ for each $y\in C$ and $x\in X$. Then $d(x,C)-d(x',C)\leq d(x,y)-d(x',C)\leq d(x,x')+d(x',y)-d(x',C)$ for each $y\in C$. Now take the infimum on the right hand side with respect to $y$. What do you get then? How does that help you to show continuity?

Comment: de right side becomes $d(x,x*)$ then right?

Comment: $d(x,x')$, yes!

Comment: i see it thanks for the tip, it follows from the epsilon delta definition. I am doing this for a course of topology so to be honest i thought at first that i needed to check the inverse of an open set, is it possible to do it that way as well?

Kees